# What's the maximum number of subnets of class C there could be if in each there should be at least 12 hosts?

Tags: subnet

Class C means that 24 bits are reserved for the network.

Comment: Wrong site, subnet questions are probably more suited for ServerFault.

Comment: yet another site! The subnet category is here too.

Comment: @simpatico: Just because someone's created a tag here doesn't mean that that persons question was correctly located either... And either way, if it's about writing code for calculating the subnet mask, it would probably be ok, just that your question/answer isn't very development oriented.

Comment: Class A/B/C networks haven't been used in 10 years. If this is coming from a textbook, then get your educational facility to get newer curriculum (not only that but the question makes no sense)

Answer (score 1):

2^4 = 16 subnets.
4 bits are to be reserved for the host, while the other 4 could be used for subnets.